# If $p,q\in N$ satisfy the equation $x^{\sqrt{x}}=\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^x$, then which one of the following is correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If $p,q\in N$ satisfy the equation $x^{\sqrt{x}}=\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^x$

(A) relatively prime

(B) twin prime

(C) coprime

(D) if $\log_q{p}$ is defined then $\log_p{q}$ is not and vice versa.

My attempt is as follows:-

$$x^\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac{x}{2}}$$
$$x^{\frac{x}{2}-\sqrt{x}}=x^{0}$$
$$x=2\sqrt{x}$$
$$x^2=4x$$
$$x=0,4$$

But there is only one root which is a natural number. So $p$ and $q$ may be equal here but then no given option will match. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Note that $x=1$ is a solution too, since $1^k=1^l\not\implies k=l$.

Comment: but why am I not getting it while solving

Comment: Because you claimed $x^y=x^0\implies y=0$, which fails if $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment noted, $p,\,q\in\{1,\,4\}$. So if we require $p\ne q$, without loss of generality $p=1,\,q=4$. This satisfies (A) and (C) (which as best I can tell are synonyms) and (D).

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-The number $0$ can be taken as solution because calculation gives $0^0=0^0$.

On the other hand we should have $x\gt0$ so
$$x^{\sqrt{x}}=\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^x\Rightarrow \sqrt x\ln(x)=x\ln\sqrt x=\dfrac x2\ln (x)$$
It follows first if $\ln(x)\ne0$ then $\sqrt x=\dfrac x2$ so $4x=x^2$ then $x=4$ and second if $\ln(x)=0$ then $x=1$.
Thus there are three solutions are $0,1$ and $4$.

You can answer now taking the three possibilities $(p.q)=(0,1),(0,4)$ and $(1,4)$ (*not necessary to consider the couple inverted such as, for example $(4,1)$*.)